# Launcher for Zenmap (or nmapfe) as SUDO

Tags: nmap

I've installed nmap, and also nmapFE. By default these are NOT set up to run as root; however, the tasks I need to run require it. I am able to run sudo nmapfe from terminal; however, if I create a launcher for this, it doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gksu in your launcher

```
gksu zenmap
gksu nmapfe
```

You can edit the zenmap launcher with alacarte. Screenshots of alacarte and configuration of the zenmap launcher:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

[image: alacarte]

[image: gksu zenmap]

Answer (score 0):

(An update to this answer in case anyone else stumbles across this post)

For Ubuntu 18.04 and later:

```
sudo apt install zenmap alacarte
```

Then either type `alacarte` in the terminal or open it through the apps drawer

Click on the **Internet** icon as shown above, then click properties

In the **Command:** text box type

```
su-to-root -X -c zenmap %F
```